# Fill tilt template using hash

Tags: ruby, erb, tilt

I got following ruby example:

```
require 'tilt'
data = { "site_link" => "http://www.example.com", "title" => "example"}
template = Tilt.new('../templates/test.erb', :default_encoding => 'UTF-8')
output = template.render(data)

puts output
```

and this is test.erb file:

```
This should be a link - <%= site_link %>
```

I can't find a proper syntax to get a value from data hash into template.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This code produces an empty output instead of site_link value. What's the syntax to have <%= site_link %> replaced by value?

Answer (score 1):

Ok,
it looks like I need to specify to tilt that data are a hash. Correct code is:

```
output = template.render(Hash,data)
```